# TYPO3 URL slug excludes folders?

Tags: slug, typo3-9.x

It seems TYPO3s new sites-tool for URLs (slugs) for pages exclude folders in the page tree: is there a configuration to include them (again, like in RealURL)? 
It is possible to change the "folder" to a "standard page", but in my case it is a big site with almost 100 folders ...

Comment: Can you please be more specific on your scenario? Why are the pages of type "system folder" instead of "standard page"? What's the problem you're currently experiencing?

Comment: We use folders (together with categories) to structure and organize pages (more than 3.000 so far), p.e. using years as folder, so a link to a page should look (and did with realURL): url/seiten/year/type/title-of-the-page, "seiten", year and type being folders. so now the link ist just url/title-of-the-page

Comment: It is about the website of a diligent Austrian MP: petrabayr.at, each page is rather like a news post, navigation is provided by a pageteaser.

Comment: hi Oliver, did my answer not meet your expectations, or do just have no time these days (which I'd understand completely ...)? I'm still curious how to solve this ...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible by default.
For more Information see this issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87452#note-9

As described there you can use EXT:masi or a similar extension to achive this:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/masi/